# Como pegar do último registro ao primeiro

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Tenho esses nomes na minha tabela:

> ```
> nome
> -----
> A
> B
> C
> D
> E
> F
> ```

Se faço:

```
SELECT nome FROM tabela
```

ele vai me retornar *"A, B, C, D, E, F"*.

Gostaria que me retornasse ao contrário, do último registro ao primeiro.

> F, E, D, C, B, A.

Como poderia fazer?

Comment: SELECT nome FROM tabela order by nome DESC

Comment: sua pergunta está mal formulada. Se a ordem dos nomes for `A B F C D E` nem `order by nome DESC` nem `order by id DESC` vai retornar o desejado. Agora, se a ordem de entrada na tabela for alfabetica, tanto faz ser por nome ou id DESC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode ordenar o seu retorno através do [`order by`](https://www.diegomacedo.com.br/como-ordenar-o-resultado-de-uma-consulta-no-mysql-order-by/):

```
SELECT nome FROM tabela ORDER BY nome DESC
```

Comment: mas eu não gostaria necessariamente de ordena-lós de Z até A. Só gostaria de pegar do último registro até o primeiro.

Comment: então a ordenação deve ser feita pelo `id`, ao invés do nome? é isso?? ou seja, ordenar do maior para o menor _id_ ao invés de ordem alfabética?

Comment: Faz sentindo, viajei kkk. Valeu!

Comment: @dds, uma das soluções é utilizar o `id`, caso ele seja auto_increment, ou então criar um campo com a data de cadastro, mas o único método de ordenação para o que tu pediu é usando o  `order by`, só tem que ver o(s) campo(s) que tu deseja ordenar.